# Two quotients of projective modules are equal, prove the crossed direct sums of the projective modules and kernels are isomorphic. (Schanuel's Lemma)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, direct-sum

We have the following:

$$\alpha_1:P_1\rightarrow M$$

$$\alpha_2:P_2\rightarrow M$$

with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ surjective, and $P_1,P_2$ projective.
Prove $$P_1\oplus \ker(\alpha_2) \cong P_2\oplus \ker(\alpha_1).$$

I don't know what properties of projective modules I should use.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_lemma

Comment: Great, thanks!!